# how to display only the first result of an array that is fetched from the database?

Tags: php, arrays

Currently I have a code that gets the data from the database and a foreach loop that list all the result. But I want to display one result at a time. Just to warn you, I'm really new to this. Really appreciate your help.

```
function featured_topics(){
    $featureNum = 162;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT *
        FROM `topics`
        WHERE `country_id` = '$featureNum'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $featured_topics[] = $row;
    }
    return $featured_topics;
}

function get_featured_topic(){

    $get_topics = featured_topics();
    $topic_count = sizeof($get_topics);
    $current_topic = $get_topic[$topic_count];

    echo $current_topic['topic_id'];
}
```

Comment: It looks like the code you have will only print one row from the database. Do you want to print all of them? Also, what do you mean by "one result at a time" -- does that mean you would give a number (say N) and it would return the Nth row?

Comment: Yes. e.g. I want to pass a num 1 and get result 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function featured_topics(){
    $featureNum = 162;
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT *
     FROM `topics`
     WHERE `country_id` = '$featureNum' LIMIT 0,1");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    return $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_result($query, 0, 'column')
```

0 represents the 0'th row.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in the way you want.

SQL rows don't have an intrinsic order, so there's no guarantee that the next time you execute this query the rows will be in the same order. Here is what might happen:

Query result:

```
points | name
--------------------
    23 | Iceland
    83 | Georgia
     8 | Spain
    10 | Argentina
```

You take the 1st row (Iceland). Then later, you do the same query. You get back this result:

```
points | name
--------------------
    83 | Georgia
    23 | Iceland
     8 | Spain
    10 | Argentina
```

Whooops! Now you got Iceland again and lost track of Georgia.

**Solutions to this dilemma**

1. Grab all the rows at once, cache them, then cycle through them at your leisure. I believe this is the best solution.
2. Specify some order using "ORDER BY", and be prepared to deal with issues where rows are inserted during your iteration.

Comment: Thanks. This might be another problem that I wasn't aware of.